# Excel Accept Changes

Tags: excel, vba

On sheet I have the following VBA code;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    If ActiveWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then

        ActiveWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges , , Where:=ActiveSheet

    End If

End Sub
```

However, when I select the sheet I get the following error message;

> Method 'AcceptAllChanges' of object '_Workbook' failed

What is wrong with my code? How do I get it to work?

Comment: Won’t Active.Workbook.Save True. save the changes?

Comment: @SolarMike I added that but still the same error message, I'd also rather not save every time the sheet is activated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 2 commas when you specify a parameter by its name.

And `Where:=` is looking for an address. So something like …

```
ActiveWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges Where:=ActiveSheet.Cells.Address(External:=true)
```

might work. Or …

```
ActiveWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges Where:="'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!" & ActiveSheet.Cells.Address
```